# What does the m in mVariableName mean?

Tags: c++, naming

I've seen several occurrences in tutorials where i variables with an "m" in front of the actual name.
At first I thought it meant "my" but after really keeping a lookout for these "m"'s I'm no longer sure what it means. Does anyone know where this convention comes from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's commonly used to mean that variable is a member of class. For example it's useful in situations like this:

```
someclass::somefunc()
{
...
.
.
  m_myvar = 1;
  lvar = 2;
.
.
.
}
```

You can tell at a glance that `m_myvar` is a member of `someclass` but `lvar` is not.

Answer (score 5):

`m` is to indicate that it is a *member* variable, it is common variant on Hungarian Notation. Other common prefixes to look out for are `I` for *interface* and `C` for *class*.

Depending on the language, it is also common to prefix `s` for *string* and `b` to indicate a *boolean*.

Comment: I thought the s prefix was for static

Comment: It can also be a prefix for `static`. In C/C++, JS, Python I have seen it used for `string`. It depends on the language.

Answer (score 1):

One common use for `m` as a prefix is "member", as in a member of a class in an object-oriented language.

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense, even obvious when i think about :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no established convention on what variable names can mean, especially their prefixes.

Basically the camel casing with the first small letter normally indicates a local variable, existing only in the current execution scope. Here m can stand for "module variable", e.g. the variable that exists only in the given module and that is not global. But this is just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a slight variant on what is called [Hungarian Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation), which encodes some type information in the variable name.

As mentioned by the other posters an "m" would usually be used to indicate the variable is a class member.